# PHP: type casting and change of the element in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, casting

I faced with a strange situation today. I need to change array element in foreach loop. As we know it can be done by using reference.

```
 foreach((array)$output['subjectComposite'] as &$subjectComposite){
     $subjectComposite['subjectSchemeVersion'] = $cellValue;
 }
```

But above code doesn't work and 'subjectSchemeVersion' is not set. At the same time if I remove (array) it works:

```
 foreach($output['subjectComposite'] as &$subjectComposite){
     $subjectComposite['subjectSchemeVersion'] = $cellValue;
 }
```

Can you explain this behaviour to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By casting the `$output` variable to array, you make a copy of it. The `&` still works, but it refers to the copy. After the loop, the copy is forgotten/garbage collected, and the original `$output` was never changed.

You can do the following instead, this will convert `$output` to an array prior to the loop:

```
settype($output, 'array');
foreach($output['subjectComposite'] as &$subjectComposite){
    $subjectComposite['subjectSchemeVersion'] = $cellValue;
}
```

Comment: Credit for the example goes to `Nick J`, he made a suggested edit :-)